# Change iPhone's default Browser

Tags: iphone, safari, jailbreak, openurl

Is there any way to alter the application an iPhone uses to view websites so that Safari isn't opened by default?

I'm thinking it may be possible with a Jailbroken phone by editing an application's Info.plist to trick the iPhone into thinking a 3rd Party browser is Safari or using some form of openURL to handle all NSURL calls.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Cydia app and install "Browser Changer" from BigBoss. Then go into the settings, Browser Changer, and select what ever browser you want as the default.

Comment: This is only possible with jailbroken iphones/itouches

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on non-jailbroken phones.

Comment: And would be very difficult to implement on those that are.